# Swift, sprite kit game: Have circle disappear in clockwise manner? On timer?

Tags: swift, timer, xcode6, sprite-kit

Alright, so I don't know the name for this but I have a sprite kit game (a runner game) that, when it's game over, is going to have a "save me" button and a timer that runs out accordingly. When the timer runs out, you can no longer click the button and save the character.

I don't want to display this timer in text however- I want a circle that "unwinds itself," if you will, and disappears at the rate that the timer runs out. I.e. when the timer reaches 0, the circle has fully disappeared. The circle disappears degree by degree in a clockwise motion in accordance with the timer.

Here are some pictures to explain what I'm talking about. [image]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By changing the `path` property of an `SKShapeNode` at a fixed interval, you can create a frame-by-frame animation sequence. To create the animation, set the `path` property to a sequence of shapes that starts with a circle and ends with nothing. You can use [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/), a wrapper for `CGPath`, to create shapes for the animation using the following steps:

1. Move path's "pen" to the center of the circle
2. Add an arc to the path with [addArcWithCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:) from a `startAngle` to `endAngle`
3. Add a line to the path from the point on the circle corresponding to the ending angle to the center
4. Change the `endAngle` by a fixed amount
5. Repeat steps 1-4

Here's an implementation of the above steps:

```
override func didMove(to:SKView) {

    let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    circle.fillColor = SKColor.blue
    circle.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
    circle.zRotation = CGFloat.pi / 2
    addChild(circle)

    countdown(circle: circle, steps: 20, duration: 5) {
        print("done")
    }
}

// Creates an animated countdown timer
func countdown(circle:SKShapeNode, steps:Int, duration:TimeInterval, completion:@escaping ()->Void) {
    guard let path = circle.path else {
        return
    }
    let radius = path.boundingBox.width/2
    let timeInterval = duration/TimeInterval(steps)
    let incr = 1 / CGFloat(steps)
    var percent = CGFloat(1.0)

    let animate = SKAction.run {
        percent -= incr
        circle.path = self.circle(radius: radius, percent:percent)
    }
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:timeInterval)
    let action = SKAction.sequence([wait, animate])

    run(SKAction.repeat(action,count:steps-1)) {
        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration:timeInterval)) {
            circle.path = nil
            completion()
        }
    }
}

// Creates a CGPath in the shape of a pie with slices missing
func circle(radius:CGFloat, percent:CGFloat) -> CGPath {
    let start:CGFloat = 0
    let end = CGFloat.pi * 2 * percent
    let center = CGPoint.zero
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to:center)
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter:center, radius: radius, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)
    bezierPath.addLine(to:center)
    return bezierPath.cgPath
}
```

and a video clip:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly

Comment: Hey @0x141E you helped me out on this question a few months ago and now I'm trying to figure out how to stop the countdown. Could you maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598907/swift-how-to-invalidate-timer-on-animated-skshapenode-countdown ? Thanks

Comment: @skyguy you'll need to add a key to the action and remove the action using the key. The issue is you can't use a key if your action has a completion handler. I'll try to come up with a workaround for that.

Comment: Ok. It would be great if you could post the code for the workaround once you get it.. I've never used keys to remove actions but I will look into it and try

Comment: This does not compile in Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but is it possible to avoid the fuzzy/jagged perimeter of the circle?

Comment: @Crashalot did you implement the code or are you referring to the video?

Comment: implemented the code, fuzziness question (and answer) posted in case you want to adapt your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317484/swift-and-spritekit-how-to-implement-non-fuzzy-circle-timer-with-skshapenode/51327545#51327545

Comment: If you call a parameter "percent" then 1.0 should represent 1/100th of whatever you are measuring. 100.0 would then be the number to go all the way around the circle. "percent is a really bad name for that parameter. You still get an upvote though.