# Swift: how to invalidate timer on animated SKShapenode countdown?

Tags: swift

Alright I'm building a sprite kit game and on one of my previous questions, I got the code that lets a circle skshapenode "unwind" in accordance with a timer that runs out (so that the circle has disappeared by the time the timer is done).

Here was my question: [Swift, sprite kit game: Have circle disappear in clockwise manner? On timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038703/swift-sprite-kit-game-have-circle-disappear-in-clockwise-manner-on-timer)
And here is the code that I've been using:

```
func addCircle() {

        circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
        let circleColor = UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 204/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        circle.fillColor = circleColor
        circle.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
        circle.position = CGPoint (x: self.frame.size.width * 0.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.5+45)
        circle.zPosition = 200
        circle.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
        addChild(circle)

        countdown(circle, steps: 120, duration: 5) { //change steps to change how much of the circle it takes away at a time

                //Performed when circle timer ends:
                print("circle done")
                self.gameSoundTrack.stop()

                self.removeAllChildren()
                self.removeAllActions()
                self.viewController.removeSaveMe(self)

                self.GOSceneNodes() //Implements GOScene
                self.viewController.addGOScene(self) //Implements GOViewController
        }

    }
// Creates an animated countdown timer
    func countdown(circle:SKShapeNode, steps:Int, duration:NSTimeInterval, completion:()->Void) {
        let radius = CGPathGetBoundingBox(circle.path).width/2
        let timeInterval = duration/NSTimeInterval(steps)
        let incr = 1 / CGFloat(steps)
        var percent = CGFloat(1.0)

        let animate = SKAction.runBlock({
            percent -= incr
            circle.path = self.circle(radius, percent:percent)
        })
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(timeInterval)
        let action = SKAction.sequence([wait, animate])

        runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(action,count:steps-1)) {
            self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(timeInterval)) {
                circle.path = nil
                completion()
            }
        }
    }

    // Creates a CGPath in the shape of a pie with slices missing
    func circle(radius:CGFloat, percent:CGFloat) -> CGPath {
        let start:CGFloat = 0
        let end = CGFloat(M_PI*2) * percent
        let center = CGPointZero
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(center)
        bezierPath.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: true)
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(center)
        return bezierPath.CGPath
    }
```

This all works well, however I need a way to invalidate the countdown for the circle if another button within the game is pressed so that everything that is performed when the timer runs out (everything after `//Performed when circle timer ends:` above) is NOT performed.

I have tried

```
        circle.removeAllActions()
        circle.removeFromParent()
```

when the button is pressed, however this just removes the circle and everything is still executed even though the circle is gone.

I'm pretty new to Swift and I can't figure out what part of those 3 functions I need to invalidate or stop in order to stop the countdown from finishing. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop an action by adding a key to the action and then run

```
removeActionForKey("actionKey")
```

To add a key to the action, replace the `countdown` method with the following:

```
// Creates an animated countdown timer
func countdown(circle:SKShapeNode, steps:Int, duration:NSTimeInterval, completion:()->Void) {
    let radius = CGPathGetBoundingBox(circle.path).width/2
    let timeInterval = duration/NSTimeInterval(steps)
    let incr = 1 / CGFloat(steps)
    var percent = CGFloat(1.0)

    let animate = SKAction.runBlock({
        percent -= incr
        circle.path = self.circle(radius, percent:percent)
    })
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(timeInterval)
    let action = SKAction.sequence([wait, animate])

    let completed = SKAction.runBlock{
        circle.path = nil
        completion()
    }

    let countDown = SKAction.repeatAction(action,count:steps-1)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([countDown, SKAction.waitForDuration(timeInterval),completed])

    runAction(sequence, withKey: "actionKey")
}
```