# How do I change arc in Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have made a pieSlice graphic with an arc in Sprite Kit.

Something like this.

```
self.path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(self.halfpi-startangle), endAngle: CGFloat(self.halfpi-endangle), clockwise: true)
self.path.addLineToPoint(center)
self.path.closePath()
self.pieSlice = SKShapeNode(path: self.path.CGPath)
self.pieSlice.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.8, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0
self.pieSlice.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.8, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.pieSlice.zPosition = 3
addChild(self.pieSlice)
```

Later in the program I want to change the pieSlice. For example, the endAngle. Actually I am changing it (want to) with time. So with regular time updates, the endAngle has to change. It does not (for now) has to animate very precise, just jump from one to the next size, etc.

How can I do that?

Is there something like an update command for nodes in Sprite Kit? Or can I delete the node and create a new one in its place? I cannot seem to get it working for now, so I need some help.

Comment: change the `path` of the SKShapeNode to reflect your new `path`,  I probably wouldn't go messing around with what happens inside a path, just make a new one

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038703/swift-sprite-kit-game-have-circle-disappear-in-clockwise-manner-on-timer

Comment: Thank you very much. After a view days puzzeling, I finaly found what I was doing wrong. The important part in changing an arc in Spritekit, is putting in an Action! I just updated the path and nothing happened. But in the example project I found that putting it in an Action does work. And now my version also does exactly what I want (which is: changing the arcSlice with time). THANKS!