# How to change the endAngle programmatically

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skshapenode

I would like to create an arc with Swift and SpriteKit by doing something like this:

```
func createArc(endAngle: CGFloat) -> SKShapeNode {

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(0, 0), radius: 300, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)

    let pathNode = SKShapeNode(path: bezierPath.CGPath)
    pathNode.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    pathNode.lineWidth = 50
    pathNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    pathNode.antialiased = true

    return pathNode


}
```

But how should I change the endAngle value of the UIBezierPath programmatically say in the update() function?

Comment: You will need to create a new path and assign it to the `path` property of `pathNode`. Here's an example of how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038703/swift-sprite-kit-game-have-circle-disappear-in-clockwise-manner-on-timer

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you **very** much.